# Suma con arrays en C++

Tags: c++, array

Llevo días intentando hacer un trabajo en el que me piden lo siguiente:

Diseñar una función de nombre sum que, dado un puntero a entero que apunta a la primera posición de un array de números enteros y un entero n con la longitud del array dado, devuelva la suma de todos sus valores mediante una función recursiva.

A continuación diseña un programa que lea un número entero n, que representa el número de valores que se leerán a continuación y, a continuación lea n valores que hay que almacenar en un array. Finalmente, muestra por pantalla el resultado de la suma de todos los valores del array.

Ejemplo de Entrada 1

0

Ejemplo de Salida 1

0

Ejemplo de Entrada 2

4
1 2 3 4

Ejemplo de Salida 2

10

Cuando hago que una suma me dé 0, esta no se muestra por pantalla, aquí tenéis el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int sum(int *a, int n);

int main(){
  int n = 0;
  int *a;
  cin >> n;
  if (n <= 0)
    return 0;

  a = new int[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> a[i];

  cout << sum(a, n) << endl;

  delete[] a;

  return 0;
}

int sum(int *a, int n){
  if (n == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  return sum(a, n - 1) + a[n - 1];
}
```

Comment: Si ejecuto tu programa con el array = 1,2,-1,-2, si que muestra 0 como resultado.

Comment: El problema, lo tengo en que si escribo 0 a la hora de hacer la operación, es allí cuando me sale 0.

Comment: 0+0=0 no entiendo

Comment: A ya entiendo lo que dices. Coloca en if(n==0)return a[0];

Comment: Perdon, no me explique bien. Quería decir, que cuando escribo 0 a la hora de hacer la operación, el programa se detiene y no muestra nada por pantala.

Comment: En donde tengo que poner lo del return a[0]?

Comment: En la funcion sum dentro del if. porque recuerda que la posicion 0 del array a tiene un elemento que se debe tomar en cuenta en la suma

Comment: lo he puesto y me pasa lo mismo

Comment: No es la solución pero arregla un pequeño problema

Comment: A ok. Cual seria la solucion? Si no la sabes, no te preocupes.

Comment: Intenta: int sum(int* a,n){n--;if (n==0){return a[0]} return sum(a,n)+a[n];}  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZA9bsMwDIV3nYJIlziugbTNFsUXMTIQMhMIsGlXP@gQ@OwupRh2hnYQqEcK79OjGcfqbsw8v1k2XWwJtB18cIR9rbaedCzfa6WilwqMPfkRDYEP7VkpywF87PepHvAdUuViGfRoeV88FDzbcIHjeREHTDczxKD1TowdeYIOwSAH22ILwqaOeuIwePiOJMeSvEo0dDutidsue1iGugbOzjfYM2jhFKIAHIXoOFFFovCZfhK@4etfeCGtzBfCbXCQA9qcQIoWHNiyzNnWL2Bjs@2kFm/QOi9H9sJFEk9HmbbCCdRcAbPc/jn9t9JE4qpaU15SyMdrSmyOC35tbfBSxin0NM8n9aE@1Zc6/QI "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: ... Ya entiendo. Realmente no se porque le ingresaría 0 al programa sin otro numero. En el main tienes después del primer cin esto if(n==0) return 0; lo que le indicas al programa que termine si solo se ingresa 0. Esto lo solucionas de manera simple. solo agregale un cout antes del return y listo: cin>>n; if(n==0){cout<<"-_- No se porque abriste el programa si no querías sumar nada, Pero cada quien con su problema \\\_/(°_°)\\\_/."<<endl<<"La respuesta es: 0"<<endl";return 0;}

Answer (score 0):

El código funciona bien.

El único caso en el que no se muestra resultado es cuando `n <= 0` ya que sales de la función y el programa termina.

Simplemente reemplaza estas líneas:

```
if (n <= 0)
    return 0;
```

Por estas:

```
if (n < 0)
    n = 0;
```

O estas:

```
if (n <= 0) {
    cout << 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias!